# Vivado_hls 2014.4 Ubuntu 14.04 x64 vivado includes error

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, fpga, vivado

I am running Vivado HLS 2014.4 (x64) on Ubuntu 14.04 x64.
Everything works in Vivado HLS 2012.
In Vivado HLS 2014.4 GUI and Synthesis works but compilation of testbench does not.

I am getting thousands of errors like this:

```
Building file: /home/nic30/vivado/tb_axis_test.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -DAESL_TB -D__llvm__ -D__kernel -D__global -Dglobal -Dlocal -D__local -Dconstant -D__constant -Dprivate -D__private -D__private -I/opt/Xilinx/Vivado_HLS/2014.4/include/ap_sysc -I/opt/Xilinx/Vivado_HLS/2014.4/lnx64/tools/systemc/include -I/home/nic30/vivado -I/opt/Xilinx/Vivado_HLS/2014.4/include -I/opt/Xilinx/Vivado_HLS/2014.4/lnx64/tools/auto_cc/include -I/opt/Xilinx/Vivado_HLS/2014.4/include/etc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"testbench/tb_axis_test.d" -MT"testbench/tb_axis_test.d" -o "testbench/tb_axis_test.o" "/home/nic30/vivado/tb_axis_test.cpp"
In file included from /opt/Xilinx/Vivado_HLS/2014.4/lnx64/tools/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/bits/stl_iterator.h:65:0,
                 from /opt/Xilinx/Vivado_HLS/2014.4/lnx64/tools/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/iterator:63,
                 from /home/nic30/vivado/tb_axis_test.cpp:4:
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado_HLS/2014.4/lnx64/tools/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/ext/type_traits.h:66:5: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado_HLS/2014.4/lnx64/tools/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/ext/type_traits.h:70:24: error: ‘__if_type’ has not been declared
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado_HLS/2014.4/lnx64/tools/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/ext/type_traits.h:109:5: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado_HLS/2014.4/lnx64/tools/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/ext/type_traits.h:113:24: error: ‘__if_type’ has not been declared
```

I think there is problem with some kind of libc6-dev-* but I don't know.
I have clear installation of system and I fallowed official install guide.
Does anyone met similar problem?

Comment: I had a lot of problem as well. I needed to change the compiler. Anyway, when you installed Vivado, did you install the other addiction library as it is suggested by Xilinx for Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: I did, but it was not helpful. It seems that Vivado HLS 2016.3 and Ubuntu 16.10 x64 are working fine.

Comment: wait one second: you cannot use Ubuntu 16.10. In your question there was Ubuntu 14.04. If I remember good it is NOT supported the installation of Vivado in Ubuntu > 14.04