# Vivado synthesize error

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, xilinx, vivado

i am getting an unexpected error when i try to run a synthesize.

this is the terminal error: No PRESET Parameter : [Low] PresetParam: pcw_ddr_priority_writeport_0
Abnormal program termination (11)

and the error log below

```
#
# An unexpected error has occurred (11)
#
Stack:
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/tps/lnx64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so(+0x91ab39) [0x7f96f049cb39]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/tps/lnx64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so(JVM_handle_linux_signal+0xb6) [0x7f96f04a2f26]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/tps/lnx64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so(+0x917753) [0x7f96f0499753]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x354b0) [0x7f97228924b0]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_ippcw.so(zynq::ps7_v1_4::pcw::backend::xml::parser::parse_presets(zynq::ps7_v1_4::pcw::backend::xml::xmliter)+0x891) [0x7f96f7d53411]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_ippcw.so(zynq::ps7_v1_4::pcw::backend::xml::parser::parse(char const*)+0x425) [0x7f96f7d5e175]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_ippcw.so(zynq::ps7_v1_4::pcw::backend::global::loadxml(std::string const&)+0x20) [0x7f96f7d25c40]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_ippcw.so(zynq::ps7_v1_4::zynq_config::ZTop::_init_common()+0xd8) [0x7f96f7da1698]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_ippcw.so(zynq::ps7_v1_4::zynq_config::ZTop::zynq_Init(std::string const&, std::string const&, std::string const&, std::string const&, std::string const&, std::string const&)+0xd8) [0x7f96f7db6168]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_ippcw.so(zynq::ps7_v1_4::instance::instance(std::map<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> > > const&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&)+0xd3) [0x7f96f7d0d723]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_ippcw.so(zynq::ps7_v1_4::instance_wrapper::instance_wrapper(std::map<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> > > const&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&)+0xaf) [0x7f96f7d9a39f]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_ippcw.so(processing_system::PSU_Interface::createInstance(std::map<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> > > const&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&)+0x1cc) [0x7f96f7f1c13c]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_iptasks.so(+0xedb31) [0x7f96c8021b31]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/libtcl8.5.so(+0x331f5) [0x7f971e97c1f5]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/libtcl8.5.so(+0x76bbe) [0x7f971e9bfbbe]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/libtcl8.5.so(TclObjInterpProcCore+0x2fb) [0x7f971ea00b8b]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/libtcl8.5.so(+0x331f5) [0x7f971e97c1f5]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/libtcl8.5.so(Tcl_EvalObjv+0x32) [0x7f971e97c7e2]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/libtcl8.5.so(TclEvalObjEx+0x322) [0x7f971e97e5d2]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_common.so(hdi::tcltasks::task_manager::eval_in_tcl(Tcl_Interp*, Tcl_Obj*, char const*, bool)+0x7fd) [0x7f97239020cd]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_coregen.so(HACGTclEvalScopeCmd::eval(bool const&)+0x94) [0x7f9713f78dc4]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_coregen.so(HACGCController::evaluateScopeCommand(std::string const&, HACGTclEvalScopeCmd&, std::string&)+0x6f) [0x7f971343f7af]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_coregen.so(HACGCController::evaluateProcCmd(std::string const&, HSTVector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&, std::string&)+0x14b) [0x7f97134480cb]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_coregen.so(HACGCController::parseArgsandEval(std::string, std::string&)+0x107) [0x7f97134496b7]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_coregen.so(HACGCCustomController::initProjectSpecificData(HSTVector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&, bool)+0x6f) [0x7f971345c79f]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_coregen.so(HACGCCustomizer::loadController(HSTVector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&, bool)+0x188) [0x7f97134206b8]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_coregen.so(HACGCCustomizer::loadCustomizationData(HSTVector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&, bool)+0x48) [0x7f9713420838]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_coregen.so(HACGCCustomizer::buildCustomizationInfo(HSTVector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&, HACGCCustomizerBase::IP_Flow)+0xec) [0x7f9713420bec]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_coregen.so(HACGCCustomizerBase::loadCustomizationData(HSTVector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&, HDGUIStatus&, HACGCCustomizerBase::IP_Flow const&)+0x172) [0x7f97134234c2]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_coregen.so(HACGIPInstBuilder::customizeIPInst(HACGIPInst*, HACGCCustomizerBase::IP_Flow const&, HSTVector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&) const+0x3f6) [0x7f97133ec6d6]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_coregen.so(HACGIPInstBuilder::createIPInst(std::string const&, std::string const&, HACGIPData const*, HACGCCustomizerBase::IP_Flow const&, HACGIPDesignContext const&, HSTVector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&, HACGBlock*, bool) const+0x93a) [0x7f97133ed5aa]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_coregen.so(HACGIPMgr::createInstance(HACGIPData const*, std::string const&, std::string const&, HACGBlock*, HACGIPDesignContext const&, bool, HSTVector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&, HDGUIStatus&, bool, bool, HACGPart const*, bool)+0x553) [0x7f971333abf3]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_coregen.so(HACGIPMgr::createScopedIP(std::string const&, std::string const&, std::string const&, HDDASrcFile*, HACGIPDesignContext const&, HSTVector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&, HDGUIStatus&, HDDAModuleRef*)+0x28b) [0x7f971333c18b]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_coregen.so(HRSBMoDiagram::addIP(std::string const&, std::string const&, std::string const&, HSTStringSmartMapCI<HRSBMoParamValue> const&, HDDAModuleRef*)+0x2fa) [0x7f9713db60aa]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_coregen.so(+0x12fbb9c) [0x7f9713dcbb9c]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_coregen.so(+0x12fff5f) [0x7f9713dcff5f]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_coregen.so(HRSBMoFactory::createReposBlk(HRSBMoDiagram*, std::string const&, std::string const&, std::string const&, HSTStringSmartMapCI<HRSBMoParamValue> const&, HDDAModuleRef*)+0x1e6) [0x7f9713dd10c6]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_coregen.so(HRSBMoDiagram::addBlk(HRSBMoDesign*, std::string const&, std::string const&, std::string const&, HSTStringSmartMapCI<HRSBMoParamValue> const&, HDDAModuleRef*)+0x4d) [0x7f9713dabd7d]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_coregen.so(HRSBMoBdReaderImp::readCompInstances(HXMLWElement&, HRSBMoDesign&) const+0x1382) [0x7f9713e604c2]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_coregen.so(HRSBMoBdReaderImp::readDesign(HXMLWElement&, HXMLWElement&, HRSBMoDesign&) const+0x77) [0x7f9713e68667]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_coregen.so(HRSBMoBdReaderImp::ReadFromXML(HXMLWElement&, HRSBMoDiagram*) const+0x214) [0x7f9713e68974]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_coregen.so(HRSBMoBdReader::Load() const+0x38) [0x7f9713e58d88]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_rsb.so(HRSBEnEngineMgr::openDesign(std::string const&, HRSBMgr*, HRSBEnCompositeFile*)+0x55f) [0x7f96fdd5da0f]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_rsb.so(HRSBEnCompositeFile::openDesignStealthMode(HDGUIStatus&, bool&)+0x10e) [0x7f96fdd2e2be]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_rsb.so(HRSBEnCompositeFile::_generateFor_(HSTVector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&, HDGUIStatus&, bool)+0x4b7) [0x7f96fdd366c7]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_filemgmt.so(HDDACompositeFile::generateFor(HSTVector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&, HDGUIStatus&, bool)+0x494) [0x7f970453fef4]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_filemgmt.so(HDDACompositeFile::generateFor(HDDATypes::GenerationTarget, HDGUIStatus&, bool)+0x85) [0x7f9704540325]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_tcltasks.so(+0x12918b9) [0x7f971823b8b9]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_tcltasks.so(+0x1292752) [0x7f971823c752]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_common.so(+0x5b7707) [0x7f9723900707]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/libtcl8.5.so(+0x331f5) [0x7f971e97c1f5]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/libtcl8.5.so(+0x76bbe) [0x7f971e9bfbbe]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/libtcl8.5.so(+0x7e767) [0x7f971e9c7767]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/libtcl8.5.so(TclEvalObjEx+0x77) [0x7f971e97e327]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_common.so(+0x5b6e1c) [0x7f97238ffe1c]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/libtcl8.5.so(Tcl_ServiceEvent+0x87) [0x7f971e9f0b37]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/libtcl8.5.so(Tcl_DoOneEvent+0x129) [0x7f971e9f0e69]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_commontasks.so(+0x2dc525) [0x7f971a883525]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_commontasks.so(+0x2e3d0b) [0x7f971a88ad0b]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_commontasks.so(+0x2dc7c3) [0x7f971a8837c3]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_common.so(+0x5b7707) [0x7f9723900707]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/libtcl8.5.so(+0x331f5) [0x7f971e97c1f5]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/libtcl8.5.so(+0x76bbe) [0x7f971e9bfbbe]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/libtcl8.5.so(+0x7e767) [0x7f971e9c7767]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/libtcl8.5.so(TclEvalObjEx+0x77) [0x7f971e97e327]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_commonmain.so(+0x6330) [0x7f9723144330]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/libtcl8.5.so(Tcl_Main+0x1d5) [0x7f971e9e9175]
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/lib/lnx64.o/librdi_common.so(+0x5f0409) [0x7f9723939409]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x76ba) [0x7f972233e6ba]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7f972296382d]
```

Comment: This is a Vivado crash that has nothing to do with VHDL. I suggest you post this question on the Xilinx forums.

Comment: See [Vivado Unexpected Error While Synthesizing a Project](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Welcome-Join/Vivado-Unexpected-Error-While-Synthesizing-a-Project/td-p/752875) and [Install - Operating System (OS) support on Vivado Design Tools](https://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/54242.html).  It looks like you should upgrade your Vivado version.

Answer (score 1):

First question is, as always, did the design work correctly in simulation?

My guess is, there is some error in the design, and the Vivado synthesis tool wasn't designed to recover from that error, causing the crash. There are some hints in the first message as to what the error might be, but simulation should let you clear it up.

Synthesis tools don't have to be as robust as simulators, because you are expected to correct most errors before attempting synthesis.

When you identify the error, and prove that it's the cause of the Vivado crash, it's probably worth reporting the defect to Xilinx so they can fix it in some distant future release (if they still pay attention to their customers).

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible that you cannot use UBUNTU 16.04 ([as it was explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29365464/vivado-hls-2014-4-ubuntu-14-04-x64-vivado-includes-error/40787857#40787857)).

[Here](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2016_1/ug973-vivado-release-notes-install-license.pdf) in the section Linux Support (pag. 20) is clearly written:

**Operating Systems**

Xilinx only supports the following operating systems on x86 and x86-64 processor architectures:

**Microsoft Windows Support**

- Windows 7 and 7 SP1 Professional (64-bit), English/Japanese.
- Windows 8.1 Professional (64-bit), English/Japanese.
- Windows 10 Professional (64-bit), English/Japanese.
- Vivado® Lab Edition is the only Xilinx toolset that supports Windows 7 SP1 Professional, 32-bit Operating System. Lab Edition also supports the 64-bit systems.

**Linux Support:**

- Red Hat Enterprise Workstation 7.0 and 7.1 (64-bit)
- Red Hat Enterprise Workstation 6.6 and 6.7 (64-bit)
- Red Hat Enterprise Workstation 5.11 (64-bit)
- SUSE Linux Enterprise 11.3 and 12.0 (64-bit)
- Cent OS 6.7 and 7.1 (64-bit)
- *Ubuntu Linux 14.04.3 LTS (64-bit)*

Vivado Lab Edition is the only Xilinx toolset that supports the Red Hat Enterprise Workstation 6.6 and 6.7, 32-bit Operating Systems. Lab Edition also supports the 64-bit systems.